# Django Custom Login - Form is valid but no error

Tags: django, authentication

I'm currently trying to figure out how to customize the base Django user login functionality to add e.g. simple-captcha.

I have subclassed "`AuthenticationForm`" from `django.contrib.auth.forms`
which first looks great, but if I try to login I'm simply not able to.

I have already debugged the code and currently i only get:

> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,
>   **callback_kwargs) TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

`accounts/views.py`:

```
...
```

login form of django.contrib.auth.forms subclassed (copied) to accounts/forms.py:

```
...
```

`urls.py`:

```
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, puuh :D

views.py:

```
...
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash, authenticate, login as customlogin
...

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                customlogin(request, user)
                # Redirect to a success page.
                return redirect(reverse('post_list'))
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': LoginForm()})
```

simply extend the form (Thanks to vorujack)

```
...
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
...
class LoginForm (AuthenticationForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', views_accounts.login, name='login'),
```

the really stupid part is at the login function "form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.POST)"
You really need to pass this for the password and user and beside that and secondary request.POST for the captcha form... Oookay. Anyways, now it works.

Thanks anybody for your help, i really appreciate this community

Comment: `form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.POST)`. What is LoginForm? Whyt are you passing the POST twice?

Answer (score 1):

when I used vorujack's way made mistake，finally I found a solution

in url

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(form_class=forms.new_login_form,
    template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
```

in forms

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
class new_login_form(AuthenticationForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField(label='验证码', error_messages={"invalid": "验证码错误"})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password',)
```

Comment: the best answer:)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here.

The main one is that you've overridden the class init signature so that the first positional argument is `request`, but you pass the POST data in that position; therefore, the form will never be bound and never valid.

Secondly if the form is invalid you re-instantiate it for some reason, so the template will never show any validation errors. Unless you have a really good reason you should stick to the standard form handling structure shown in the docs.

Putting those together:

```
def login (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "You are now logged-In, welcome")
            return redirect(reverse('post_list'))
    else:
        form = LoginForm(request)

        args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html', args)
```

Note, you don't need the second `else` block; the single one here is aligned with the first `if`, and the final `return` is hit in both cases.

Comment: Hey, i just tried your solution but i get: 'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'save'. i guess that i actually dont even need it there. If i remove it, i simply dont get logged in and get redirected to post list.

Comment: you does not logged in. you only check user info and redirect to specific user. check in your view if `request.user` exists and is a authenticated user or not.

Comment: @ vorujack, my view now looks like the post from Daniel Roseman.
Can you please post you solution?

Comment: >>'LoginForm' object has no attribute 'save'<<
What do i have to change at the form? Sry im still a beginner :(

Comment: I update this answer but you view old one because Daniel not accept it

Answer (score 0):

as Daniel said you update init method of form. so you must pass request as first argument.

second is when you validate user info you must authenticate user with authentication backend. but you saved form data.

if you only want to change authentication form you can use login view like this

see below:
urls.py

```
....
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth.login, {'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
....
```

if you use django2 and above you can change it like this. first of all create a class based view extended from django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView in this class set form_class to it like this.

```
from django.conrtib.auth.views import LoginView
...
class NewLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm
```

then you must update your urls like this:

```
...
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', NewLoginView.as_view, name='login'),
...
```

you must extend your form from `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` or you must implement all needed function of this form class.

Comment: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'authentication_form'

Comment: witch version of Django do you use

Comment: Django 2.1 (current)

Comment: Beside that, this solution is quite not parical because i won't be able to add captcha field this way. to use a captcha from e.g. django-simple-captcha you need to implement it into a form directly, thats why i want to sub-class this ;)

Comment: my solution based in django2.x. i update solution for django2.1

Comment: This solution is also not pratical and does not solve my problem.
As i already mentioned in the other solutions at the bottom "captcha = CaptchaField()" - from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
is only processable in forms.py and i need it later on. Either im not able to authentificate myelf due that im not able to propperly subcalss "AuthenticationForm" from contrib.auth to insert a captcha field or im bound to this Django intelnal fuzz here... Where im able to change the look but with no captcha
There must be a solution to propperly subclass AuthenticationForm into my own forms.py right

Comment: if you don't want to extend your form class from AuthenticationForm you must implement all method in this class.

Comment: i guess i have to open a new thread on this. Now i have some more questions.
Thanks to all of you

Comment: I guess we had a misunderstanding here.
I just implemeted the stuff from above but i get:
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I also updated my post